# Encryption and Decryption using AES in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, encryption, linux-kernel

I want to encrypt files during their creation and decrypt files during their read operation using AES algorithm. I have also written code in `vfs_write()` and `vfs_read()` for encryption and decryption respectively and also it is working nicely, but the only problem now is that k whenever I pass a file to `vfs_write()` whose length is not multiple of 16 (AES BLOCK SIZE) den AES does padding to it to make it a multiple of 16 and bcz of this the size of the file increases but the `write()` function does not know about this and so it rejects

e.g.:- suppose i enter data as "123", here `length` is 4 (3 length of data + 1 '\0' character) and so AES padds 12 bytes to it to make it 16 bytes (as AES works on 16 bytes blocks), but `write()` only takes original length which was 4, and so i want to know how to change the file size to 16 (in this case) and also where to do it in kernel code.

i tried this

```
inode->i_size=new_length;
inode->i_op->truncate(inode);
```

also i tried

```
if(file->f_flags & O_APPEND)
    *pos=i_size_read(inode);
```

but this is not working bcz kernel hangs and also i am not understanding where to do such things i.e., in which function and how.

also i tried changing the count variable with new length in `vfs_write()` but then it gives error as "cat write error: No space left on device".

it works fine when i pass file which is a multiple of 16.

Comment: Do they pay you few cents for every word you write in bold? :S (interesting question, by the way)

Answer (score 1):

Your current mode requires padding; and it can be hard to do padding in some cases (like what you meet). Usually, disk/filesystem encryption is done in other mode, which require no padding (and easy to do random reads/writes).

Overview of block cipher modes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

Modes: ECB, CBC, PCBC, CFB, OFB require padding

and mode CTR (Counter) doesn't require padding.

This mode is easy and it is even easier to implement it in wrong (unsafe, easy-to-break) way.

There is an overview of Disk encryption http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory with even more advanced modes (XEX, XTS). Some of them still require padding.

Even with universal cipher mode you will get a lot of problems.. Some of them are covered in ["Cryptfs: A Stackable Vnode Level Encryption File System"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.62.6144&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Answer (score 1):

why dont you deliberately make it 16 bytes, encrypt it and then after decryption discard the padding. I mean instead of relying on aes alone, do it yourself. By this you wil be sure that the data you are getting is correct